# wchar_t to octets - in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to store a wchar_t string as octets, but I'm positive I'm doing it wrong - anybody mind to validate my attempt? What's going to happen when one char will consume 4 bytes?

```
  unsigned int i;
  const wchar_t *wchar1 = L"abc";
  wprintf(L"%ls\r\n", wchar1);

  for (i=0;i< wcslen(wchar1);i++) {
    printf("(%d)", (wchar1[i]) & 255);
    printf("(%d)", (wchar1[i] >> 8) & 255);
  }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to store them? The `printf` calls are outputting each byte as a parenthesised number. This will show you what an octet stream would contain, but it isn't an octet stream (at least, not in the way I think you mean it).

Comment: I stated that I'm trying to store it, as in - this is my goal. The printf() is the 'visual' outcome for me to judge. Do you happen to know what will happen with a char(codepoint?) which consumes 4 bytes?

Comment: Well, apparently my sample is correct. I thought wcslen() will return 1, for a char which consumes 4 bytes. But apparently it returns 2 for a 4 bytes long char, so it translates the original wchar_t as-is. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode text is always encoded.  Popular encodings are UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32.  Only the latter has a fixed size for a glyph.  UTF-16 uses surrogates for codepoints in the upper planes, such a glyph uses 2 wchar_t.  UTF-8 is byte oriented, it uses between 1 and 4 bytes to encode a codepoint.

UTF-8 is an excellent choice if you need to transcode the text to a byte oriented stream.  A very common choice for text files and HTML encoding on the Internet.  If you use Windows then you can use WideCharToMultiByte() with CodePage = CP_UTF8.  A good alternative is the ICU library.

Be careful to avoid byte encodings that translate text to a code page, such as wcstombs().  They are lossy encodings, glyphs that don't have a corresponding character code in the code page are replaced by ?.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of: "such a glyph uses 2 wchar_t.", I suppose in addition to the comment of mine on the original question, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wcstombs()` (widechar string to multibyte string) function provided in `stdlib.h`

The prototype is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t wcstombs(char *dest, const wchar_t *src, size_t n);
```

It will correctly convert your `wchar_t` string provided by `src` into a `char` (a.k.a. octets) string and write it to `dest` with at most `n` bytes.

```
char wide_string[] = "Hellöw, Wörld! :)";
char mb_string[512]; /* Might want to calculate a better, more realistic size! */
int i, length;

memset(mb_string, 0, 512);
length = wcstombs(mb_string, wide_string, 511);

/* mb_string will be zero terminated if it wasn't cancelled by reaching the limit
 * before being finished with converting. If the limit WAS reached, the string
 * will not be zero terminated and you must do it yourself - not happening here */

for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
   printf("Octet #%d: '%02x'\n", i, mb_string[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and your samples, I'm trying to understand whether wcstombs() transparently 'converts' invalid sequences, do you happen to know if it does?

Comment: If it encounters a wide character that can not be converted to a multibyte representation, `wcstombs()` will return `-1`, so nothing is done without you not knowing :)

Comment: @LukeN: That's what I was afraid of, I'm not sure what it defines as a multibyte representation? a different encoding - such as UTF-8? (my goal is to store transparently a wchar_t of 2 bytes - UTF-16LE, under windows)

Comment: I think C defines a multibyte string as just that - characters that don't fit into 1 byte will be split over multiple bytes and can be "unsplit" again later. I don't know whether or not it's clean UTF-8 when it comes out of that function :( But if you can't be sure that your widechar string contains usable characters, how should C (or in a do-it-yourself attempt: you) know HOW to split them to octets?

Comment: Thanks a lot, apparently my sample is correct - I just commented on it

Comment: The behaviour of wcstombs() depends on the LC_CTYPE category of the current locale. See setlocale().

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to see the content of the memory buffer holding the string, you can do this:

```
  size_t len = wcslen(str) * sizeof(wchar_t);
  const char *ptr = (const char*)(str);
  for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    printf("(%u)", ptr[i]);
  }
```

Comment: That's C++. The asker is looking for C.

Comment: the idea can be used in C too, the only c++ism is the reinterpret_cast thing --- is -> was ...

Comment: @ShinTakezou: But that reinterpret_cast thing does not make sense to a pure C programmer - without knowing it, they don't know it's basically the same as `(type *)&cast_me`

Comment: if wcslen() represents a codepoint, and sizeof(wchar_t) represents 2 bytes under windows - how could it possibly handle codepoints which consumes 4 bytes?

Comment: @Doori Bar: it can't. Code points are 2 bytes in Windows Unicode encoding, otherwise wchar_t would have been bigger.

Comment: I assume this is one of the flaws of UTF-16, which microsoft picked as unicode default.

Comment: @Amnon: I thought NTFS was UTF-16LE, while it's being represented as wchar_t which is 2 bytes under windows. So NTFS is not UTF-16LE?

Comment: @LukeN: I'm not sure if I understand what the flaw is?

Comment: In my opinion, UTF-16 is the worst UTF to pick. With UTF-8 you can be sure, that each and every character is a byte - it is compatible with ASCII (very important!) and doesn't waste space when it doesn't need to be wasted (if a char fits into one byte, it will be one byte, if it fits into 2 byte, it will be 2 byte). UTF-32 assures you, that each and every character is exactly 4 bytes, it's easier to handle but wastes space. UTF-16 will waste space if the character would fit into 1 char (it still uses 2) and would STILL have to split bigger characters that don't fit in 2 UTF-16 wchars.

Comment: @Doori: I don't know. I'm not sure what NTFS has got to do with it.

Comment: @LukeN I supposed the word "cast" should suggest what the "construct" tries to do, but of course it could also happen differently

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, apparently my sample is correct - I just commented on it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why printf and wprintf do not work together. Following code works.

```
unsigned int i;
const wchar_t *wchar1 = L"abc";
wprintf(L"%ls\r\n", wchar1);

for(i=0; i<wcslen(wchar1); i++)
{   
    wprintf(L"(%d)", (wchar1[i]) & 255);
    wprintf(L"(%d)", (wchar1[i] >> 8) & 255);
}
```